# using ngResource factory in controller showing error

Tags: angularjs

hi everyone I am new with angular js I want to get data through getting method using Resource I have to build a resource factory but when I call this factory in controller I got this error *Error: Users.myUser is undefined* Please anyone can tell what I have done wrong or why I am getting this error here is my code.

```
var Myapp = angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ngResource'])
    .config(['$resourceProvider', function ($resourceProvider) {
        $resourceProvider.defaults.stripTrailingSlashes = false;
    }]);
    Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return{
        myUser:
          $resource('some url', {}, {
            query: {
              method: 'POST',
              params: {},
               isArray: false
            }
        })
    };
});



Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Users) {
    Users.myUser.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return `$resource` object from `myUser` factory function.

```
Myapp.factory('Users', function($resource) {
  return {
    myUser: function() {
      return $resource('some url', {}, {
        query: {
          method: 'POST',
          params: {},
          isArray: false
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Controller

```
Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope,Users) {
    //Call myUser method like below
    Users.myUser().query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for helping me i tried your method but i still got the same error here is my updated code as instructed by you.

Comment: `Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return {
        myUser: function () {
            return $resource('http://localhost:8012/abhi/public/student', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            });
        }
    };
});`

Comment: my controller..                                                                                                         Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $state,Users) {

    Users.myUser.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    }); });

Comment: Guys please help me out its start getting complicated for me.

Comment: You have to change factory the way I suggested

Comment: bro i have changed it same the way u instructed me but still got the same error.

Comment: Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    return {
        myUser: function () {
            return $resource('http://localhost:8012/abhi/public/student', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            });
        }
    };
});

Comment: sorry  for that bro i am not pasting wrong code stackover flow not allowing me to paste my code in proper format. last comment i have paste is same as instructed by you.

Comment: i have updated it but now i am getting this error _Error: Users.myUser is not a function_.

Answer (score 0):

Update your factory as below

```
Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    function myUser() {
          return  $resource('some url', {}, {
                query: {
                    method: 'POST',
                    params: {},
                    isArray: false
                }
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: i have updated my code as instructed by but i still got the same error.here is my code`Myapp.factory('Users', function ($resource) {
    function myUser() {
        return  $resource('http://localhost:8012/abhi/public/student', {}, {
            query: {
                method: 'POST'
                params: {},
                isArray: false
            }
        });
    }
});`

Comment: Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, Users) {
    Users.myUser.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4));
    }, function (error) {
        console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4));
    });});

Comment: Guys please help me out its start getting complicated for me

Comment: Myapp.controller('DashCtrl', function ($scope, $state, $http, Users) { Users.myUser.query(function (data) { console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)); }, function (error) { console.log('Error is: ' + JSON.stringify(error, null, 4)); });});